# Ruby green_shoes styles not working

Tags: ruby, user-interface, rubygems, shoes

I am trying to use green shoes to create a GUI app to send people messages over LAN using Ruby and the Green Shoes(green_shoes) GUI library, but I am running into the issue of the .style function not working. I've worked with the original Shoes(red shoes) before and it has no issues. Here is the code for creation and style of the GUI:

```
Shoes.app(title: "Messenger", height: 150, width: 370, resizable: false) {
#creation
alert startMessage
@user_msg = para "Enter User"
@msgbox = para "Enter Message"
@user = edit_line
@msg = edit_line 
@submit = button "Send" 
@help = button "Send to PC"
@info = button "PC info"
#styles
@msg.style(:right => 5, :top => 57)
@user.style(:right => 5, :top => 25)
@user_msg.style(:left => 10, :top => 25)
@msgbox.style(:left => 10, :top => 57)
@submit.style(:left => 10, :bottom => 10)
@help.style(:left => 150, :bottom => 10)
@info.style(:right => 15, :bottom => 20)
#...
```

Comment: What is not working? Does the code have an error? If so, what error message do you receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not that the styles *"aren't working"* but rather they are unsupported.

I see reference to right and bottom in `shoes` [Source](https://github.com/shoes/shoes/blob/develop/lib/shoes.rb#L488) but not in `green_shoes` seems that positioning in `green_shoes` is from top and left always.

[Green Shoes style:right](https://ashbb.github.io/green_shoes/Styles.html#:right)

> **Note:** Green Shoes doesn't support `:right` style.

[Green Shoes style:bottom](https://ashbb.github.io/green_shoes/Styles.html#:bottom)

> **Note:** Green Shoes doesn't support `:bottom` style.

This is why Shoes3 works and green shoes doesn't.

You will have to alter all your locations to be `:top` and `:left` which isn't that uncommon in layout designers.

**Can't Wait for Shoes4 to be a full release** (even if it does require `jruby`)

<sub>Shoes4 does support bottom and right [Source](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4/blob/master/shoes-core/lib/shoes/common/style.rb#L19)</sub>

Comment: Personally I consider shoes4 more feature complete than green shoes and still actively being worked on. If you miss anything essential from green shoes please open issues or comment on issues that are important to you over at [our issue tracker](https://github.com/shoes/shoes4/issues) - sorry time has also been low.

Comment: @PragTob thank you for chiming in. I think the work going on with Shoes4 is great and I agree from a completeness and a compatibility standpoint Shoes4 is far more complete than green_shoes. I understand the time component and I appreciate all the effort that has been made to keep _why's project/dream alive.